# Show that the Riemann integration itself a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, riemann-integration

Consider the function from cts$([a,b],\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f \mapsto \int_{[a,b]}f$ where $\int$ denotes the Riemann integral. I want to prove that it is continuous.

Intuitively, I think that is true because considering the compact-open topology on the function space, if we varies the function by some small distance (under $d_\infty$), the integral will also varies by a small amount.

I think I can make use of complete metric space and the fact that if whenever a sequence of functions $f_n \rightarrow f$, $\int f_n \rightarrow\int f$ such that the Riemann integration will be continuous.

However, I am struggling on writing a formal statement about this. Would anyone give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: $|\int_{[a,b]} f(x)dx-\int_{[a,b]} g(x)dx| \leq \sup_x |f(x)-g(x)| (b-a)$.

Comment: Can you please clarly say which topology are you using on $\mathcal C([a,b],\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am using the compact-open topology.

Comment: Fine. But it would be much more natural then to say that you are using the topology induced by the the $d_\infty$ distance. Yes, it is the same thing, but it is not obvious.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ah yes sorry. In my course we were used to treat them as the same notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the $\|.\|_{\infty}$ norm on $\mathcal{C}^0([a,b])$, the linear function $I : f \mapsto \int_a^b f$ satisfies
\begin{align}
|I(f)| \leqslant \| f\|_{\infty}(b-a)
\end{align}
Hence it is continuous with respect to the topology induced by this norm.

Comment: By linearity: $|I(f)-I(g)| \le \|f-g\|_\infty (b-a)$ too, which shows we can get the distance between $I(f)$ and $I(g)$ as small as we like. It's a Lipschitz map so uniformly continuous even.

Comment: Of course. It follows from the fact that a linear map is continuous if and only if it is uniformly continuous, if and only if it is continuous at zero, etc.

Comment: The OP might not be aware of that yet..

Comment: You may be right. I personnaly believe this fact is the very first property learned while studying the continuity of linear maps, and I assumed OP knows a little bit about continuity of linear maps (as the question is about this subject). In fact, OP was originally talking about compact-open topology, that looks way more difficult to me compared to what I stated, hence my supposition.

Comment: @DIdier_ The inequality was a nice property that I didn’t notice before, instead I was reading Terrence Tao’s analysis and one of his proof shows that we can use the uniform continuity to prove this. Thanks for the hint anyways!

Comment: @DIdier_ I have added an answer using your hints, would you mind to have a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f\in cts([a,b],\mathbb{R})$, since $f$ is continuous, it is Riemann integrable and hence we can write $$\int_{[a,b]}f=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(t_{i+1}-t_i)x_i$$ where the $t$‘s represent the partition of $[a,b]$ and for some $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$. Then we have $$|\int_{[a,b]}f| = |\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(t_{i+1}-t_i)x_i| \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(t_{i+1}-t_i)|x_i| \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(t_{i+1}-t_i)\;sup\{|f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\} = (b-a)sup\{|f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}$$ which is the bound we wanted to use to prove the statement.

Now, let $f,g\in cts([a,b],\mathbb{R})$. Since the Riemann integral is linear, and since $f-g$ is continuous for any $f,g$ continuous, we have $$|\int_{[a,b]}f-\int_{[a,b]}g| = |\int_{[a,b]}f-g| \leq (b-a)\;sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[a,b]\} = (b-a)\;d_\infty(f,g)$$ hence, let $\epsilon > 0$, if we let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)}$ we have $$d_\infty(f,g)<\delta\Rightarrow |\int_{[a,b]}f-\int_{[a,b]}g|<\epsilon$$ and therefore the Riemann integral is continuous.

Comment: I am not sure for the first part (Riemann integral is defined to be the supremum of such a writing, I don't know a result saying that there exists a partition for which the integral is equals to the sum). The resting part seems right.

Comment: Thanks! I am also not sure about how to prove the inequality so I need to check for more..

Comment: It is straight forward when $f$ is continuous if you know the triangle inequality for integrals, that is $|I(f)| \leqslant I(|f|)$. It is because $|f(t)| \leqslant \|f\|_{\infty}$ for $t \in [a,b]$.